# How come state isn't reset when component is rerendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-state

Suppose I have the following inside a functional component:

`const [addComment, setAddComment] = useState(false);`

I do not understand this...
Prior to the rerender, the state of addComment has being changed to True instead of False, a rerender of the component does not change it to False again. I thought everything is reran in functional components and thus useState(false) would be called again with addComment being reset to False.

Thank you

Comment: What would even be the point of having a state if it gets reset on every render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way useState is designed: The value you pass into useState determines the **initial** value of the state. So on every render after the first, the value you pass in is ignored.